# Django Grant permission to Foreign key objects

Tags: django, python-3.x, foreign-keys

I have an `Image` model with a foreign key to `Album`. A `User` can have edit or read only permission on `Album`. How do users with edit `Album` permission, also edit `Images` under this `Album`?

Is there a simple way in Django to grant User permissions over foreign key objects?

Comment: Django doesn't have row level permissions anyway. How are you managing the permissions on the Album in the first place?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Using `django-guardian`. It provides object level permissions.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I understand that you use django-guardian. One option would be to define a function as described below (or perhaps as an Album class function?)

```
from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm

def update_album_permission(album, user, permission):
    assign_perm(permission + '_album', user, album)
    for image in album.images.all():
        assign_perm(permission + '_image', user, image)
```

Then you will need to ensure to always update user permissions through this interface.